# Represent unset values in Jackson without null

Tags: serialization, null, jackson, kotlin

I have a few API model objects defined in Kotlin, so all fields are non-nullable by default.

```
data class MyParam(val name : String,
                   val myField1 : ClassOne = ClassOne.NO_OP,
                   val myField2 : ClassTwo = ClassTwo.NO_OP)
```

For unspecified values, I use the null-objects `ClassOne.NO_OP` and `ClassTwo.NO_OP` which provide no-op implementations. This allows all other code to safely call methods on `myField1` and `myField2` without null handling.

When I serialize this object via Jackson, is there any way to specify that `myField` should not be included in the generated JSON if it equals `NOT_PROVIDED`?

Comment: How is that any better than just using `null` ? With Kotlin, you only have to do a single null check, the smart casting will then ensure that you don't have to do null checks again.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert, instances of this data class will be used all over the code. Using a NullObject pattern ensures that most of the code will not need null handling.